# Calling C++ Application Code from C library?

Tags: c, c++11, dynamic-library

Folks, Assuming I have a c++ application / library running which implements say

```
/* Alloc API */
void* my_alloc(int size) {
    return malloc(sizeof(size));
}
```

This is not under "extern c".

I have a C dynamic library from which I need to call my_alloc, can I directly call that API?

```
Like,

int test_my_alloc (int size) {
    int *x;

    x = (int*)my_alloc(size);
    if (x == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably wanted `malloc(size);` instead of `malloc(sizeof(size));`. But you will face problems as what you really need is `malloc(size*sizeof(int));`

Comment: Nope - you need to declare `my_alloc` as `extern "C"` or implement a wrapper in your C++ library which does this.

Comment: @CoolGuy that was a type, forget that, I am looking at how to call my_alloc from C library.

Comment: @PaulR, I have the restriction of being unable to the existing C++ code, so can''t do that.

Comment: OK - try to remember to include important constraints like this in your question in future. I've sketched out one possible solution in an answer below now.

Comment: Why do you ask? Please edit your question to explain that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a stub, e.g.

Stub header:

```
// stub.h

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void* my_alloc_c(int size);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Stub implementation:

```
// stub.cpp

#include "stub.h"
#include "header_where_my_alloc_is_declared.h"

void* my_alloc_c(int size)
{
    return my_alloc(size);
}
```

Your C code (example):

```
// my_code.c

#include "stub.h"

int main()
{
    void * p = my_alloc_c(42);
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile your stub and link it with your C code:

```
g++ -Wall -c stub.cpp          # compile stub.cpp
gcc -Wall my_code.c stub.o     # compile your C code and link with stub.o
```

Comment: This was thought of as well, but unfortunately this involves 100+ API wrappers for which we have to write a library, so this was being considered the last approach if we didn't find any other solution. Anyway looks like there is nothing else that can be done apart from wrapper APIs.

Comment: OK - again, this information should have been in the question - if you don't make an effort to explain the whole problem then it's like pulling teeth for anyone trying to provide a solution.

Answer (score 5):

As [Paul R. answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28992332/841108), you need a stub code. also, you'll better be sure that your C++ function does not throw [exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) (I guess that a C++ function, called from a C program and `main`, which throws an uncaught exception is having some [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). BTW, you should be sure that the constructor of `static` C++ data (like `std::cout`) is called "conceptually" before your `main` in *C* (so you better link your program with a C++ compiler, not a C one). See the [GCC `__attribute__(constructor)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.htm)

In *practice*, at least on Linux with C++ code compiled by [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (`g++`) or by [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) (`clang++`),  a C++ function has some [mangled name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

You might use some ugly and non-portable trick to call a function by its mangled name. You could dare coding:

```
 int main(int argc, char**argv) {
   extern void* _Z10my_alloc_ci(int size);
   void * p = _Z10my_alloc_ci(42);
   return 0;
 }
```

but I am a bit ashamed of giving such silly advice. You could even use [asm labels](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html#Asm-Labels) e.g.

```
extern void*f(int) asm ("_Z10my_alloc_ci");
p = f(42);
```

However, I feel that you should not have any such approaches, and I am surprized why you need to call a C++ function which is not wrapped around `extern "C"`.

Notice that in theory, C++ functions (without `extern "C"`) could even have a different -and incompatible- [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) than C functions. I don't know any implementation doing that.  So to be safe you should wrap your C++ function with some C++ wrapping using `extern "C"`

To avoid uncaught exceptions, you might catch all of them in your C++ wrapper:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
extern "C" void* my_alloc_c(int size)  {
  extern void* my_alloc(int);
  try {
    return my_alloc(size);
  } catch (...) {
     ::fprintf(::stderr, "got uncaught C++ exception for my_alloc(%d)\n", 
          size);
    ::fflush(nullptr);
    ::abort();
  }
 }
```

BTW, if your C++ library is large, you might perhaps try to automatize the generation of the glue code. For example, you could customize [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a Lispy domain specific language to extend GCC) by coding an extension in MELT which would generate the glue code when compiling the C++ header files.

You might be interested in [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) which enables you to (portably) call any (C and probably C++) function of arbitrary signature.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gathered:

1. You have a C++ library you have no control over *(you can't add the extern "C")*
2. You have a C library that must call the C++ library
3. You can modify your C library to accommodate a solution *(you can change the makefile and change the name of the function you want to call)*

**So, one alternative solution would be to compile your C library with the very same C++ compiler used for that C++ library, if that's acceptable for you.**

*Note: with C89, you'll possibly need to modify bits of your code (*e.g. void * to T * conversions are not implicit anymore in C++*), but it would probably be easier than 100+ wrappers.*

*Note 2: If you're using some C99 features (*e.g. the VLAs*), then that code will not compile in C++.*